# Show that M is complete

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Q. The metric space M consists of all ordered pairs **x** =$(x',x'')$ of real numbers with metric $\rho=max(|x'-y'|,|x''-y''|)$. Prove that M is complete.

My approach:
We know that a space is complete if every Cauchy sequence in M has a limit in M. My doubt is how do I show that any arbitrary Cauchy sequence in M is converging to the limit which lies in M?

Comment: *Hint:* if $\left\{(x_n,y_n)\right\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, show that $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: "We know that a space is complete if every Cauchy sequence in M has a limit in M" Is that your definition of complete? Or how do you define completeness?

Comment: The basic definition of completeness